# How to design my code so that it can use alternative information to help create an object

Tags: design, design-patterns

I have a class named `Product`, which takes a product model number and number of wheels for that product as part of its creation information, and then it instantiates the product by doing a computation on the number of wheels and on various base parameters

For example, `Product(5, 22)` creates a model 5 product with 22 wheels on it, where that particular product's weight and dimensions are *computed* from the number of wheels and from the base specifications for that model number.  Right now base specifications are part of the class itself and are hardcoded into the class, along with the computation formulas.

My Issue:  in the (legacy) code I am working with, I cannot always use the model number directly.  It may not be available.  Instead, an unrelated `product_id` is given, where the link between `product_id` and `model_number` is in the database.

I want to keep my class as simple as possible.  As such I do not want to introduce another constructor that allows `product_id` as an input parameter, in addition to the existing `model_number`, as it will be duplication of code.  Also, I am not too keen on putting database logic inside the class, but maybe I can, as thinking about it now, this may be a good candidate for a database-wrapper class, i.e. active record (where my base specifications can be moved off from the code and into the database).

Question:  How do I create and return the object while following good object oriented principles when the `model_number` I typically use for its creation is not available, but another parameter is available instead (`product_id` in this case), which links 1:1 to `model_number`?

Sample solutions that I don't quite  like:

- Do not involve the database -- since I am working with just a few Products at this time, and Products do not change often, I can create a "conversion function" that serves as a map between `product_id` and `model_number` and not touch the database.  Similarly, create a `Convert` object that has same functionality and use it before creating the object.  Problem:  duplicating DB functionality in the code.
- Put DB functionality inside code and add alternate constructor.  Problem:  multiple entry-points of Product creation for the class create code duplication.

**Update:**

There basically are 3 aspects here:

- base data (whether hardcoded or part of the database)
- finding base data by various parameters be it model number or other identifying information
- doing computation using base data as per model number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to build upon the solution @TMN is presenting and take it a little further to answer your SRP problem. Putting database code inside the `ProductFactory` would be non-sensical so to encapsulate this responsibility you can create a separate class `ProductModelNumberProvider` with just one method `findByProductId(int productId)`.

The `ProductFactory` should provide a setter `setProductModelNumberProvider(ProductModelNumberProvider lookupProvider)` which will assign the provider internally and call `findByProductId()` when appropriate.

You will have a `ProductFactory` which is responsible for building the product and a `ProductModelNumberProvider` which will do the database interaction if needed.

[Have a look at your StackOverflow question for a more concrete example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642135/how-to-create-factory-class-to-supply-a-product-from-different-parameters/22643248#22643248)

Comment: special thanks to Bart for helping me here and on SO as I negotiated various OO concepts with what I already knew

Comment: I am accepting this answer as it introduces concept of Provider and overall gave me a fuller picture of what it means to do OO with SRP.

Comment: I am curious: it is stated that Provider is not a pattern (http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/04/27/Providerisnotapattern/) ad reading more about it, it seems that generally people dislike using this construct.  I was curious to ask you if there is a need to reconsider using this construct?

Comment: *Provider* is just a part of the name. Don't think in patterns too much :) If I called it a `Helper` would it make any difference?

Answer (score 7):

Maybe create a `ProductFactory`, with methods to create a `Product` given a number of wheels and either a product ID or a model number.  Given a model number it defers to the class' constructor, and if given a product ID it performs the DB lookup, gets the model number, then defers to the class constructor.

Comment: in this case, is it okay to put DB lookup and object creation in one class?  I am a little lost trying to super-separate classes by using SRP, but maybe I'm taking it too far.

Comment: @Dennis The SRP can apply on different levels. For example, the purpose of the factory is to build a Product object given the input parameters. So the factory has all the logic it needs to do just that, including the necessary logic to get info from a DB. Still one single responsibility, just on a higher level. Of course your factory shouldn't have SQL queries in it, but it can call a function or two on a repository object.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to duplicate the DB mapping `product_id -> model_number` by hardcoding the logic, that makes sense. So the first thing you need *is* a function  like

```
int mapProductIdToModelNumber(int product_id)
```

which does this mapping by getting the information from the database (consider caching when this function is used very often).

What remains is how to make this function available to your `Product` class without tight coupling. You have the following alternatives:

- pass the function directly to the code blocks whereever `Product` objects are created (depends on your programming language how to accomplish that)
- implement the function in a `ProductFactory` class. Derive `ProductFactory` from an interface `IProductFactory` and pass an object of this type to the code areas where you currently want a `new Product()`. Use the factory the way @TMN suggested.

That way, your legacy code stays decoupled from the database, since it won't depend directly from a database-bound `ProductFactory`, only from `IProductFactory`, which can be easily mocked out (for example, for testing purposes).

Comment: Thanks.. it sounds similar to a database wrapper, where `mapProductIdToModelNumber` is same or similar to `findModelById()`, which I can also call from a `ProductFactory`.  But then why pass it as a function, why not instantiate the Object where the database is being used and call that function from the object?  (Except in my case it is legacy code and there is no database class, so I see your point on just passing the function using some language facility...)

Comment: @Dennis: the central point is the separation of concerns. Passing `mapProductIdToModelNumber` will allow you, for example, to exchange the function against one without any DB access (which might be helpful for testing purposes). It will also allow you not only to keep your `Product` class decoupled from the database, but also you `ProductFactory`.

Comment: While I agree on separation of concerns, adding additional indirection through lookup method passing is unnecessary complexity. If you already have such function, then there is no real need for factory itself and you can just call the function and then call the constructor. The single responsibility of the factory would be to encapsulate of the lookup so the calling code doesn't have to worry about how the product is created. Simply said "If you have to tell factory how to create the object, then there is no point in the factory."

Comment: @Euphoric: the OP wants the computational code for creation in one place, and the database code in another, decoupled. So the natural solution I see is to put the computational code into the factory, and inject the db mapping function into the factory. Mixing these two things into one function or class will be a showstopper for unit testing.

Comment: OP says nothing about "computational code for creation". There is computation inside Product(based on parameters passed to constructor), creation (normal constructor with no logic) and DB lookup for finding the parameter for construction. And having bare constructor call + DB lookup in factory seems fine to me. Only logic the factory will contain is the DB lookup. Nothing else. But I'm not sure and hope OP clarifies this.

Comment: well it is not necessary, but is certainly convenient to be able to instantiate the product from the place where I need it. So i.e. in a certain code block I have access to the `product_id` and I need an instance of the `Product`.  Ideally I want to get this instance in a single (or can be several) lines of code that all reside inside the same code-block.  Which classes or functions are called behind the scenes are less important, but should do data retrieval, finding, and computation, be they in the same place or not.  So in short, call the instance and do computation as part of the call.

Comment: @Euphoric: see my edit

Comment: The more I am thinking of doing OO (see my other answer with 4 classes in it), the more I like this way. it is procedural but has much less pain to it.  I have to create a new file for `Provider` class anyway, I might as well create a file with that one conversion function in in and just call it in my object constructor like `Product(lookup[$productId], $wheels)`

Comment: @Dennis: my first suggestion is not *procedural*, but *functional*. My second suggestion is a more object oriented version of the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this -- give up the idea of a `Product` class and create a DB-wrapper where I will say `$pf = ProductFinder()`, then do `$pf->findById()` and `$pf->findByModel()` as needed.  Problem:  Where do I put my *computation* code?  It can't be in the same place, as it it will violate Single Responsibility Principle.  aka, computation and data handling should be separate.  Then maybe `Product` class can be the computational part, and `ProductFinder` be the database pulling part.

Answer (score 0):

What I actually ended up doing:

At first I was wondering if I am better off with such complexity.

**Simpler way was:**

There is another pattern here that I could use that keeps things in one class:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2175213/2883328.  Breaks SRP.

```
$product = Product::fromProductId($productId, $wheels);
```

**SRP way** (chosen)

- `ProductData` class that just has the data (can be swapped by database later)
- `ProductFactory` class that uses Provider class to look up the model number
- `ProductNumberProvider` class that provides model number when given product id
- `Product` class that does loads ProductData and does computations

Code:

```
$provider = new ProductModelNumberProvider();
$factory = new ProductFactory($provider);
$product = $factory->constructFromProductId($productId, $wheels);
```